# page not displaying with ng-resource

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am having a problem with ngResource. When i add it as a dependencie my app displays blank page. I dont use ngResource for now all i do is declare it as a dependencie. And i have added the script needed for ngResource in my html file. please help

my angular controller looks like this :

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', ['ngResource']);

app.controller('loginController',
  ['$scope', '$location', 'AuthService',
  function ($scope, $location, AuthService) {

    $scope.login = function () {

      // initial values
      $scope.error = false;
      $scope.disabled = true;

      // call login from service
      AuthService.login($scope.loginForm.username, $scope.loginForm.password)
        // handle success
        .then(function () {
          $location.path('/');
          $scope.disabled = false;
          $scope.loginForm = {};
        })
        // handle error
        .catch(function () {
          $scope.error = true;
          $scope.errorMessage = "Invalid username and/or password";
          $scope.disabled = false;
          $scope.loginForm = {};
        });

    };

  $scope.posts = [];
  $scope.newPost = {created_by: '', text: '', created_at: ''};

  $scope.post = function(){
    $scope.newPost.created_at = Date.now();
    $scope.posts.push($scope.newPost);
    $scope.newPost = {created_by: '', text: '', created_at: ''};
  };
}]);

app.controller('logoutController',
  ['$scope', '$location', 'AuthService',
  function ($scope, $location, AuthService) {

    $scope.logout = function () {

      // call logout from service
      AuthService.logout()
        .then(function () {
          $location.path('/login');
        });

    };

    $scope.gotoregister = function () {




          $location.path('/register');


    };

}]);

app.controller('registerController',
  ['$scope', '$location', 'AuthService',
  function ($scope, $location, AuthService) {

    $scope.register = function () {

      // initial values
      $scope.error = false;
      $scope.disabled = true;

      // call register from service
      AuthService.register($scope.registerForm.username, $scope.registerForm.password)
        // handle success
        .then(function () {
          $location.path('/login');
          $scope.disabled = false;
          $scope.registerForm = {};
        })
        // handle error
        .catch(function () {
          $scope.error = true;
          $scope.errorMessage = "Something went wrong!";
          $scope.disabled = false;
          $scope.registerForm = {};
        });

    };

}]);
```

My main html file looks like this :

```
<!doctype html>
<html ng-app="myApp">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>MEAN Auth</title>
  <!-- styles -->
  <link href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootswatch/3.3.6/yeti/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>

  <div class="container">
    <div ng-view></div>
  </div>

  <!-- scripts -->
  <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.1.min.js"></script>
  <script src="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.4.9/angular.min.js"></script>
  <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.4.9/angular-resource.min.js"></script>
  <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.4.9/angular-route.min.js"></script>
  <script src="./main.js"></script>
  <script src="./services.js"></script>
  <script src="./controllers.js"></script>
  <script src="./chirpApp.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Any error messages in your browser console?

Comment: http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/X.Y.Z/angular-resource.js Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
angular.js:4470 Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.4.9/$injector/modulerr?p0=myApp&p1=Error%3A%2…udflare.com%2Fajax%2Flibs%2Fangular.js%2F1.4.9%2Fangular.min.js%3A20%3A274)(…)

Comment: can you help please

Comment: It says `Error 404 (Not found)` - what's the URL of the file that cannot be found (check the network tab in your console/developer tools)? I suspect it has nothing to do with ngResource.